# Stuck at sending an array of numbers using HTTPie

Tags: json, httpie

I want to send this JSON using HTTPie:

```
{
    name: 'John',
    phones: [
        1234,
        5678
    ]
}
```

And this is the parameters that I add to the `httpie` command:

```
name=John phones[]:=1234 phones[1]:5678
```

However, it does not compile (shows error).

If I remove those colons:

```
name=John phones[]=1234 phones[1]=5678
```

It works, but I get this JSON being sent as the body:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "phones[][1]": "1234",
    "phones[][]": "5678"
}
```

How can I get that body? What parameters should I provide?

Comment: Quite useful if you share the error you're getting.

Comment: Just follow the [instruction](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/introduction), and use: `name=John phones[]=1234 phones[]=5678`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the index, try:

```
name='John' \
phones[]=1234 \
phones[]= 5678 \
```

---

The `:=` in your first try indicated '[Raw JSON fields](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/non-string-json-fields%5C)', so if you'd like to use that, use:

```
phones:='[1234, 5678]'
```